# How do I fade in a loading div while data is retrieved using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, loading, fadein

My site uses a `$.get` function to send data provided by a link to a PHP script which retrieves data from a database and echos that data back to the `$.get` function which then uses a `.html(data)` function to fade in the data and present it in a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.topNavLink').click(function() {
        $.get('/view/scripts/data.php', { 'page' : $(this).text() }, function(data) {
            $('#contents').fadeOut(100, function() {
                $('#contents').html(data).fadeIn(100)
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`.topNavLink` is of course the class for every link in the navigation menu, and the function reads the text between the link's tags to find the name of the page.

I have a `<div id='#loading'>` which is initially hidden by the CSS with `opacity:0`. I wish to use a `.fadeIn(100)` function to fade in the div when a `.topNavLink` is clicked, then call the code above loading the contents of the page and finally fade out the div.

I've tried calling the div fadeIn before the `$.get` like so:

```
$('.topNavLink').click(function() {
    $('#loading').fadeIn(100);
    $.get('/view/scripts/data.php', { 'page' : $(this).text() }, function(data) {
...
```

I've tried using the fadeIn's callback option like so:

```
$('.topNavLink').click(function() {
    $('#loading').fadeIn(100, function() {
        $.get('/view/scripts/data.php', { 'page' : $(this).text() }, function(data) {
...
```

But eventually it ends up not showing the div or not loading the contents.

What am I doing wrong (and hopefully my intention is clear and you know what I'm trying to accomplish)?

Comment: it should be <div id='loading'>  - without the hash in the id!

Comment: Typo when posting the question here, in the real code it doesn't have the hash. My bad :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not hide the `#loading` div with `opacity:0` but with `display:none` for fadeIn to work.

Comment: You sir, just scored a massive amount of points on my "likes" list. This actually fixed it! :D
Thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome, if this was the answer to your question, please mark it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of events (http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) you can use to show your loading div. I suggest trying `beforeSend` because it will be fired before the ajax call occurs. You would have to rewrite your ajax call a little bit (it's probably not 100% correct but it should illustrate my point):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/view/scripts/data.php',
    data: $(this).text(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#contents').fadeOut(100, function(){
            $('#loading').fadeIn(100);
        });
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#loading').fadeOut(100, function(){
            $('#contents').html(data).fadeIn(100);
        });
    }
});
```